# Lumen get public directory

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I want to store an image file with response like

```
http://localhost/storage/image/someimage.jpg
```

But when tried to use storage_path it returned

```
/home/../../../someimage.jpg
```

here's what i tried

```php
   if ($request->hasFile('avatar_image')) {
      $image = $request->file('avatar_image');
      $name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $destinationPath = storage_path('images');
      $image->move($destinationPath, $name);

    $detail->update([
          'avatar_image' => env('APP_URL').$destinationPath.'/'.$name
       ]);
    }
```

Is there any way to get only the storage directory like `/storage/image/...`
so i can concat it with my app_url

Comment: Plese edit your question and add your blade `img` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so what i did was symlink my storage/images with public folder then put it like

```php
if ($request->hasFile('avatar_image')) {
    $image = $request->file('avatar_image');
    $name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $destinationPath = storage_path('images');
    $image->move($destinationPath, $name);
    $file_path = env('APP_URL').'/public/images'.$name;

    $detail->update([
        'avatar_image' => $file_path
    ]);
  }
```

it did works but dont know if its good enough